# Display colored text in Adobe Acrobat Reader

Tags: color, acrobat

Hello everybody out there using TeX,

Sorry for molesting you with a question involving closed-source software, but Adobe's Acrobat Reader on Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't display colored text within my document, whereas evince for example does.
Can anyone of you reproduce this minimal example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
Hello, \color{blue}{world}!
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can see the colors without any problems (Win 7, Sumatra and AcroRead) Use `xcolor` it has one more `x` in it must be better :)

Comment: I don't see any problem here : just tried with Okular 0.15.3, Adobe Reader 9.5.1, epdfview 0.1.8 and even PDF Xchange Viewer 2.5 (all under KDE 4.9). Check your install of Adobe Reader (by the way, under Linux you don't really need Adobe reader since there are plenty of good readers).

Comment: acrobat (windows at least) has an option to replace the document colours in its accessibility options. Are you sure that isn't checked?

Comment: why do we need to provide another MWE?

Comment: Adjusting the accessibility options indeed solves the problem. I should have read the Acrobat Reader documentation more carefully.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Based on the comment by the OP, your comment is the answer. Please convert :-)

Answer (score 5):

Acrobat (windows at least) has an option to replace the document colours in its accessibility options. If this is checked then you can not control the colours from within the pdf file as the reader will replace them with colours chosen to help with colour  distinctions.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems on Windows when using some alternative fonts. Use `\textcolor` instead of `\color`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
Hello, \textcolor{blue}{world!}
\end{document}
```

The \def of `\textcolor` uses `\leavevmode`. You could try `\leavevmode\color{blue}` also.

Comment: Trying `\textcolor` was also my first idea. Unfortunately it didn't work.